# Page Reload and/ or page redirect not working in $ajax success function

Tags: jquery, ajax, webforms, asp.net-3.5

I am using `$ajax` jQuery function to post data to code-behind method of ASP.NET 3.5 webform which is working all fine, except my `window.location` for redirect and/ or `location.reload` is not firing.

I have also tried `widnow.location.href` but still no success. I am getting alert call for The Staff Been Removed From Selected Role Successfully. I am not really sure what I am missing here

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'SelectRoleToRemove.aspx/RemoveRoleFormSelectStaffProfile',
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ GivenStaffID: selectStaffID, GivenRoleID: selectedRoleID }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);

        if (response.d == "The Staff Been Removed From Selected Role Successfully") {

            widnow.location = "RemoveStaffFromRoles.aspx?staffID=" + selectStaffID;

            location.reload();
        }
        else {
            window.location = "Roles.aspx";
        }

    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
}).done(function (response) {
    //
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Typo `widnow.location`, should be `window.location` or try `location.href`